# How (and why) could a post be “removed from network questions”?

Tags: discussion, support

A recent [question’s](https://law.stackexchange.com/posts/98206/revisions) edition history shows that it was “removed from network posts” by one of the moderators. Why is it possible for doing this, and what are valid reasons for which a moderator might be able to do it?

Answer (score 2):

### Some questions attract the wrong attention.

When a question attracts too many bad answers from being a hot network question or just is an ill fit to be an ad for a site, that status can manually be revoked. It is a more extensive step than just protecting the question against users with less than 20 reputation.

Reasons for it can be:

- [What kinds of question titles put a site's HNQ presence at risk?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318792/what-kinds-of-question-titles-put-a-sites-hnq-presence-at-risk) - SOME question types put the sites privilege to have Hot network questions **at all** at risk. The Interpersonal Stack is stuck with this.
- As an answer on that same question explains, **certain content** is automatically ineligable for HNQ. It doesn't invalidate the question, but advertising for such content is problematic. Among other things, forced intercourse is such a topic, as are any other topics that can be triggered.
- [Does SE have some general, non-website-specific guidelines of removing questions from the HNQ network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349179/does-se-have-some-general-non-website-specific-guidelines-of-removing-questions) - this cites the original post that talked about removing from HNQ, and the proposal there is, emphasis mine:

> In general, **we recommend that you exclude questions that attract negative attention to your sites**, that is, **questions that are controversial, start large amounts of debate or arguments or even edit wars.** Removing a question should not be a substitute for fixing it! Remember that it may take several hours for a moderator to respond to a flag so do what you can, first:
>
> - If the title seems click-baity or doesn't adequately describe the question, edit it!
> - If the body is full of spelling or grammatical errors, fix them!
> - If the body contains unnecessary detail or salacious content, see if it can be removed without impacting the question.
> - If the question is unclear or broad, vote to close it. In most cases it will be better to close a question and wait for it to be improved rather than asking for it to be removed.

### THAT question in particular

The question was decidedly about a type of hate crime. Hatecrime is a trigger to many, and problematic as no matter how it is phrased it is always attracting the wrong crowd: people who have no idea of the law, and then vote for answers that cater to their group, or write bad answers.

Remember, that a question is not suitable as a Hot Network Question, and thus ad for the community does **not** mean that it is a bad question. It just means, that the question is not suitable to be used to point to our community.

Comment: Yes but what criteria should be used to decide if something is an ill fit to be an ad for a site?

Comment: @TylerDurden Included all the links you need.